# How to get a string result in AsyncTask android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a class `AsyncCallWS`  that get content from webservice. It worked well. However, I want to get result in the class `AsyncCallWS`, namely  `returnServer` string in the `MainActivity` . Could you help me to solve it?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    String resultRegister;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button btnRegister =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            new AsyncCallWS().execute("123");
            Log.d("DDD",resultRegister);
            if(resultRegister.equals("")) {

                Log.d("D", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("E", "False");
            }
        }
    });

 }

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            String id_num = params[0];

            //toast(id);
            String url_registerID="server path"+id_num ;

            try {

                String returnServer=getStringContent(id);
                Log.d("D",returnServer);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove 3rd parameter `Void` from this `AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>`

and replace it with `String`, i.e;

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

After changing you'll get compilation errors in your `doInBackground()`.. just change the return type from `Void` to `String`

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
```

Now you can get the String returned by this method in `onPostExecute(String result)`

The `String result` here is the String which is returned by `doInBackground()`

***EDIT ***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

String resultInActivity;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  new AsyncCallWS().execute("123");
  //How to get respond from AsyncCallWS
 }

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        String id_num = params[0];

        //toast(id);
        String url_registerID="server path"+id_num ;

        try {

            String returnServer=getStringContent(id);
            Log.d("D",returnServer);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnServer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        resultInActivity = result; 

        if(resultRegister.equals("")) {

            Log.d("D", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("E", "False");
        } 

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
     }

  } // Asyntask ends

} // activity ends
```

The response from `AsyncTask` is produced in `onPostExecute()` from there you can perform tasks based on the response etc.

I highly recommend you read the [AsyncTask Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thank Sharp Edge. How to get it in MainActivity?

Comment: @user8430 just put your `AsyncCallWS` class inside the `{ }` of the Activity class.. make it a private inner class, the you can declare an instance variable .. then assign the value of `String result` to that variable and then use it any where

Comment: It crashed sir. I call the get result in onClick and it crashed

Comment: why would you call result in onClick ? result is null unless the thread is complete.. Thats why it crashes.. You should tell your scenario or update your question accordingly

Comment: Because I want to get the result after I click the button

Comment: get the result where ? do you want to `Toast` it ? Just update your question with your latest problem and I will answer it

Comment: @user8430 you should perform the `if()` checks in `onPostExecute` method of `AsynTask` instead of `onClick`

Comment: I want to called AsyncCallWS in OnClick and it will return the value in there. For example, I have a button Registration. When I click it, It will send a request to server and server will return a string. If not, it will be null. Then, in onclick I will check if return is string that means it ok. otherwise, it false. That is reason why I call it in Onclick

Comment: @user8430 you have no knowledge of how threading works do you ? A thread performs tasks which is not bound by main thread. AsyncTask in your case is a Thread class which creates a Thread. so when you call `new AsyncCallWS().execute("123");` the next line after will be called immediately because that line is on main thread. So anything you want to do after the AsyncTask thread completes must be done in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: You can call `new AsyncCallWS().execute("123");` in onClick but you should not check the result in onClick.

Comment: Yes, I know. Do you have any idea for that

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Threading in Android first. Try [this official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Answer (score 0):

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask

Replace the third parameter with String which results doInBackground return String and corresponding postExecute method parameter as String

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params)

protected void onPostExecute(String result)
```

In Order to get it on MainActivity you have to do the following Steps

1. Create an Interface anywhere you want to and declare a method of any name which should have parameter of type String

   ```
   interface ResponseHandler 
    {
    void onResponse(String result)
    }
   ```
2. In the MainActivity you have to implement that interface and you will 
   get the data here in this method

   ```
   ResponseHandler handler = new ResponseHandler(){
     @override
     public void onResponse(String result)
      {
        // enter code here
     }
     };
   ```
3. After implementing this interface you can provide the instance of it to the AsyncTask constructor.

   ```
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(handler);
   ```
4. You will get the reference of ResponseHandler in AsyncTask

   ```
      public AsyncTaskClass(ResponseHandler handler)

        {
       this.handler = handler
        }


        //enter code here

       void onPostExecute(String result)

       {

      handler.onResponse(result)
       }
   ```

This way you will get the result in your MainActivity.